# Keycloak and C++ Integration

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I have to integrate `Keycloak` with an already existing C++ App, made up of several microservices. The database that is being used is `MongoDB`. Worth mentioning is that this app is a Desktop Client and will continue to be that way. I find Keycloak docs not that straightforward and would like some help on how to implement the security of the app to be delegated to `Keycloak`.

Saving the users and `Keycloak` data in `MongoDB` would be a nice feature. But as far as I know, that is not supported anymore, so I used `PostgreSQL` as a Keycloak specific DB.

From my research, I have found out that if I want to receive an Access Token without a browser, I have to use the `Direct Grant` feature in Keycloak. So making a `POST` request to

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

with my data (`client_id`, `client_secret`, `username`, `password`, `grant_type=password`) would supply me (the app) with an access token and a bunch of other data. The question is, is this the right way? If not, what should I do?

What about user registration?

What am I supposed to do with the access Token, my data is in my `MongoDB`?

Can you direct me to some *plain-english* tutorial/docs for keycloak?

Thank you.

Comment: Removed the C++ tag. This question is about generic integration with Keycloak.

Comment: Nope, I dropped Keycloak and decided to go another way

Comment: @Renis1235 what other way did you decide to go? I have also been looking for a similar solution with the tech-stack you mentioned in your question above. Do you think it would be the right way to explore?

Comment: @ManishVerma I used my implementation to handle this. There could be definitely a way to get this up and running, but I cut short and dropped the whole thing before investing countless hours in it.